# Symfony2, How to create a Drop Down menu based on Class Constants?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have one class with some constant value like below :

```
class MyClass
{
    const ACCESS_NONE = 0;

    const ACCESS_SUBMIT = 1;

    const ACCESS_VIEW = 2;

    const ACCESS_APPROVE = 3;
}
```

How can I create something like below in my twig file with Symfony2 :

```
        <select name="someName">
            <option value="ACCESS_NONE">None</option>
            <option value="ACCESS_VIEW">View</option>
            <option value="ACCESS_SUBMIT">Submit</option>
            <option value="ACCESS_APPROVE">Approve</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As drupality said you can write a method like that:

```
public static function getConstantsChoices()
{
    return array(
        self::ACCESS_NONE => 'None', //or 'ACCESS_NONE' => 'None' if you want the string
        self::ACCESS_VIEW => 'View',
        self::ACCESS_SUBMIT => 'Submit',
        self::ACCESS_APPROVE => 'Approve',
    );
}
```

and if you use a form, you can use a choice:

```
->add('name', 'choice', array(
      'choices' => MyClass::getConstantsChoices()
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create class with proper interface:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-list

[Interface API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/ChoiceListInterface.html)

You can always create array by hand, but if you want to get constant names in PHP, the only way is reflection:

[How to get name of the constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880148/how-to-get-name-of-the-constant)