# Has any way to convert a name of constant or definition in a String? [php]

Tags: php, constants

I have a function in PHP that I must pass a string parameter into. I have a file with many constant definitions, like:

```
define('MSG_CATEGORY_THINGS', things);
```

I would like to transform my constant `MSG_CATEGORY_THINGS` into a string with value `'MSG_CATEGORY_THINGS'` without putting single quotes in the parameter.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What's the expected result?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php#100449

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880148/how-to-get-name-of-the-constant

Answer (score 0):

You could recieve all your constants by:

```
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
$myConstants = $constants["user"];
```

This will return an associative array, i.e.

```
['MSG_CATEGORY_THINGS'=>things]
```

If you want it as strings you could do:

```
extract($myConstants)
```

You will now have a variable called `$MSG_CATEGORY_THINGS` with a value of `things` :)

Comment: I've thought about this in the context of multilingual messages.  Gettext uses strings, but conceivable one might use a database with a numeric key for your translations.  This convertability answer allows you to abstract the implementation of getting your translated string in a pretty easy way